# Using pySerial with Python 3.3

Tags: python, pyserial, python-3.3

I've seen many code samples using the serial port and people say they are working codes too. The thing is, when I try the code it doesn't work.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port=0,
    baudrate=9600
    # parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    # stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    # bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

ser.open()
ser.isOpen()

print(ser.write(0xAA))
```

The error it gives me is : "SerialException: Port is already opened". 
Is it me using python3.3 the problem or is there something additional I need to instal ? Is there any other way to use COM ports with Python3.3 ?

Comment: If anyone asks, I have COM1. I use it a lot. It wasn't opened by another program on the time I tried this code. When tried with Docklite opens COM1 successfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the moral of the story is.. the port is opened when initialized. `ser.open()` fails because the serial port is already opened by the `ser = serial.Serial(.....)`. And that is one thing.

The other problem up there is `ser.write(0xAA)` - I expected this to mean "send one byte 0xAA", what it actually did was send 170(0xAA) zeros. In function `write`, I saw the following :
`data = bytes(data)` where data is the argument you pass. it seems the function bytes() doesn't take strings as arguments so one cannot send strings directly with: `serial.write()`, but `ser.write(bytearray(TheString,'ascii'))` does the job.

Although I am considering adding:

```
if(type(data) == type('String')):
    data = bytearray(data,'ascii')
```

in `ser.write()`, although that would make my code not work on other PCs.